# Checkboxes in Rdlc Report

Tags: rdlc

I am creating rdlc report and i have issue that i got some bool type object fields and now i have to show checkboxes. but there is nothing i found for this solution to show checkboxes in table.

Is there anyone who know that how i can implement that thing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I got solution 
here is the link download the project and run it.

http://uploading.com/files/2mmf34m8/Nestle%2BNew.rar/

i have developed class and then used list to set bool variable true/false. while on other hand i used image control in rdlc report To set image.

You just need to set image path which are already in image folder.

Cheers.

Comment: I believe the file is removed from website. :/

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement that the checkboxes have a background color. I liked the simplicity of a text-based rather than image-based approach, so I used a variation of the popular Wingdings-font method: I used a small, square textbox with a thin border and the specified background color, set it to use a bold, sans-serif font, and used this expression for the text value:

```
=IIf(Fields!SomeBool.Value, "X", "")
```

If you still want a checkmark rather than an X, you can use Wingdings 2 font and this expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!SomeBool.Value, Chr(80), "")
```

In either case, you may have to adjust the font size and/or box size to keep the result square; my first take was taller than wide because it expanded vertically to accommodate the font.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put image there, depend on true or false, just display different pic. LOL

Answer (score 0):

If checkbox is true I set `Chr(254)` else show unchecked checkbox using `Chr(168)`.

`Chr(254)`: This is decimal value for Wingdings character 254 its shows like checked check box image.
`Chr(168)`: This is decimal value for Wingdings character 168 its shows like rectangle box like unchecked check box image.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set the textbox placeholder to render tags as html and then put this html in: Or you can set the Placeholder expression to support HTML and then set up the following html code:

```
<font face="Wingdings 2" color="green">@Html.Raw(((char)0x51).ToString())</font>
```

You should put in the character of the wingdings that you want.
This way, only part of the text can be wingdings.
 [Wingdings 2](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html)